# PHP-EWS move email to folder

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I am using php-ews to get attachment and save them to specific directory and now i need to move the mail into another folder. Im stuck in here :

```
$client = new Client($host, $username, $password, $version);

$request = new FindItemType();
$request->ParentFolderIds = new NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();

// Return all message properties.
$request->ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType::ALL_PROPERTIES;
// Search in the user's inbox.
$folder_id = new DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$folder_id->Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId[] = $folder_id;
$response = $client->FindItem($request);
// Iterate over the results, printing any error messages or message subjects.
$response_messages = $response->ResponseMessages->FindItemResponseMessage;



foreach ($response_messages as $response_message) {
     // Make sure the request succeeded.
     if ($response_message->ResponseClass != ResponseClassType::SUCCESS) {
         $code = $response_message->ResponseCode;
         $message = $response_message->MessageText;
         continue;
     } 

     $items = $response_message->RootFolder->Items->Message;
     foreach ($items as $item) {
         $subject = $item->Subject;
         $sender = $item->From->Mailbox->EmailAddress;
         //move mail item from folder "INBOX" to folder "DONE"
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you end up with a working solution? It would be great if you could update the question to tell us. Cheers!

Comment: I finally move to another system. This lib is too slow and needs to write lots of code for simple things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I eventually found a solution (see my answer below) but I really agree with your comments about the lib. You need to write 50 lines of code to execute a simple command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **working solution**, using php-ews 1.0

You can use the existing class `MoveItemType`

```
    $request = new MoveItemType();

    $request->ItemIds = new NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
    $item_id = new ItemIdType();
    $item_id->Id = 'foobarfoobar';
    $request->ItemIds->ItemId[] = $item_id;

    $request->ToFolderId = new TargetFolderIdType();
    $folder_id = new FolderIdType();
    $folder_id->Id = $this->treatedFolderId;
    $request->ToFolderId->FolderId = 'barbar';

    $response = $this->client->MoveItem($request);
    $response_messages = $response->ResponseMessages->MoveItemResponseMessage;
    foreach ($response_messages as $response_message) {
        // Make sure the request succeeded.
        if ($response_message->ResponseClass != ResponseClassType::SUCCESS) {
            // Error treatment .....
            continue;
        }
        $items = $response_message->Items->Message;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [MoveItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa565781(v=exchg.140).aspx) operation.

Create a class file. Save it to EWSType/MoveItemType.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Definition of the MoveItemType type
 *
 * @package php-ews
 * @subpackage Types
 */

/**
* Definition of the MoveItemType type
*/
class EWSType_MoveItemType extends EWSType
{
    /**
    * ToFolderId property
    *
    * @var EWSType_TargetFolderIdType
    */
   public $ToFolderId;

   /**
   * DistinguishedFolderId property
   * 
   * @var EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType
   */
   public $DistinguishedFolderId;

   /**
   * ItemIds property
   *
   * @var EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType
   */
   public $ItemIds;
}
```

Then do something like the below in your application code:

```
// Generic connection sample code
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $username, $password);

$request = new EWSType_MoveItemType();

$request->ToFolderId->FolderId->Id = 'FOLDER_ITEM_ID_VALUE';
$request->ToFolderId->FolderId->ChangeKey = 'FOLDER_ITEM_CHANGE_KEY_VALUE';

$request->ItemIds->ItemId->Id = 'ITEM_ID_VALUE';
$request->ItemIds->ItemId->ChangeKey = 'ITEM_CHANGE_KEY_VALUE';

// Generic execution sample code
$response = $ews->MoveItem($request);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($response, true).'</pre>';
```